# Field validation in Django Serializer not being called

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm building a password manager using Django for the back end.

When a user submits a new set of credentials to store them in their vault I'd like to add the prefix 'http://' if it isn't already present in the data for the url field.

I'm trying to validate the url field using the field validator functionality in Django's Serializer, here is my Serializer currently:

```
class StoredCredentialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.URLField()

    class Meta:
        model = StoredCredential
        fields = ['user_id', 'title', 'username', 'password', 'url']

    def validate_url(self, value):
        validator = URLValidator()
        try:
            # Validating the URL format using Django's URLValidator
            validator(value)
        except ValidationError:
            # If the URL format is invalid, try to correct it by adding the prefix
            if not value.startswith(('http://', 'https://')):
                value = 'http://' + value  # Add 'http://' prefix to the URL
            
            try:
                # Validate the modified URL format
                validator(value)
            except ValidationError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid URL format")
        
        return value
```

When I pass a url to it without 'http://' or 'https://' it returns a 400 bad request error which indicates the 'validate_url' function is not being called. I'm unsure why as I seem to have followed the format in the Django documentation. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As you're using `serializers.URLField()` in the serializer, that field automatically validates for a url using regex as mentioned in the [docs here](https://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#urlfield). It means you can skip the `http` validation, or use `serializers.CharField()` to validate manually.

EDIT:

The serializer will first validate the declared `URLField` using its own validators. If it passes, then only your `validate_url` method will be called. So, if your method is called, it's guaranteed that the url has [http/https/ftp/ftps](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/validators.py#L69) prefix in the value.

You have two options as of now.

1. Allow validation by serializer and add https after its validation.
2. Use `CharField` and validate everything manually

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As mentioned in the docs you linked, it 'Expects fully qualified URLs of the form 'http://<host>/<path>''. I'm trying to append the 'http://' if the submitted URL doesn't already contain that using the validate_url function but it doesn't seem to be called in my current code. Do you know why? Or am I going about that the wrong way?

Comment: @wildgoose Edited my answer

Answer (score -2):

If field validation in a Django Serializer is not being called, there could be a few reasons behind this issue. Here are some common troubleshooting steps:

- Ensure validate_<field_name> Method Exists:

  Make sure you have defined a method named validate_<field_name> in your serializer class for the field you want to validate. For instance, if you want to validate a field named email, the method should be named validate_email.
- Check Serializer Naming Convention:

  Ensure your serializer is named correctly and is being used properly in views or other parts of your Django application. The serializer should be referenced correctly where it's being utilized.
- Verify Serializer Invocation:

  Double-check that you're invoking the serializer correctly in your views or wherever you're using it. If the serializer is not being used or initialized properly, the validation methods won't be triggered.
- Check Serializer Context:

  Ensure that the serializer is being passed the appropriate context if the validation logic relies on context data. Context can be passed when instantiating the serializer.
- Inspect Field Naming and Structure:

  Confirm that the field name in the serializer matches the field name in the model. Also, verify the field structure to make sure it aligns with the validation logic you've written.
- Inspect Serializer and Model Relationship:

  Ensure that the serializer class is associated with the correct model and the fields are correctly mapped between the serializer and the model.
- Debug and Logging:

  Introduce logging or debug statements within the validation methods to check if they are being called or if there's an error occurring within these methods.

Here's an example of how a field validation method should be defined within a Django serializer:

python

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
email = serializers.EmailField()

def validate_email(self, value):
    # Validation logic for email field
    # Return validated value or raise a ValidationError if invalid
    if not value.endswith('@example.com'):
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Only emails from example.com domain are allowed.")
    return value
```

Ensure that the naming convention (validate_<field_name>) is followed correctly for the field you want to validate.

If the issue persists after checking these points, reviewing the code where the serializer is being used and examining the overall structure of the serializer and associated views/models might provide more insight into the problem.

Comment: This is just chatgpt straight out of the box. Not hugely helpful . . .